# How to aggregate and add values in Mongo DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Am having below dataset where need to group by field A and add the unique values to the existing or new field. Tried addtoset without any success. Any help here is much appreciated

Dataset

```
A    B      C
xyz  green  blah
xyz  amber  other blah
xyz  red    asdasda
cdd  green  asdasdad 

Expected

A B
xyz,[green,amber,red]
cdd,green


.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$RAG" }, 
{$group : {_id : {A:"$A",B:"$B"}}},testRag: { $addToSet: "$B" }]).toArray(function(err, output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$A",
            "B": {
                $addToSet: "$B"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "A": "$_id",
            "B": "$B"
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "A" : "cdd",
    "B" : [
        "green"
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "A" : "xyz",
    "B" : [
        "green",
        "amber",
        "red"
    ]
}
```